# Python 2: How do I pull a value from a matrix of options based on multiple test values?

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures

Let's say I have two colors of blocks, `red` and `blue`. Let's also say that blocks have a number on them (regardless of color, and numbers can be repeated). So we could have the following blocks:

```
block_one = {"color": "red", "value": 1}
block_two = {"color": "red", "value": 3}
block_three = {"color": "blue", "value": 1}
```

I have the following table of prices:

```
    Red    Blue
1    10     15
2    20     17
3    30     19
```

What is an efficient way for me to figure out the price based on the two pieces of data I have for each block?

Example: What is the price of block_one, and I want an output of 10.

I've been writing nests of `if-elif` testing multiple dictionaries of prices, but it is 1.) convoluted and ugly and 2.) slow.

Comment: How big is the amount of data?

Comment: 5,000 - 10,000 records.